# 500(Internal Server Error) using API webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call a `Web API` Put method from a `MVC5` Client Web Service class. I am able to get the book to edit by its id, but when I edit anything, I get this error

> Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).

I have searched to get some information on what is causing this error, but am not being able to find what is the actual issue. Can someone please help in pointing out what I am doing wrong.

API Controller

```
// PUT: api/Books/5
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(int id, BookDetailDTO book)
{
    try{
        var bookEdit = db.Books.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);

        if(bookEdit == null){
            return BadRequest();
        }
        else{
            bookEdit.Title = book.Title;
            bookEdit.Year = book.Year;
            bookEdit.Price = book.Price;
            bookEdit.Author.Name = book.AuthorName;
            bookEdit.Genre = book.Genre;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = book.Id }, bookEdit);
        }
    }
    catch{
        if (!BookExists(id)){
            return NotFound();
        }
        else{
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

BookService method

```
public void UpdateBook(int? id, BookDetailDTO book)
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + MyToken.myToken);
    BookDetailDTO bookDetailDTO = new BookDetailDTO();

    bookDetailDTO.Id = book.Id;
    bookDetailDTO.Title = book.Title;
    bookDetailDTO.Year = book.Year;
    bookDetailDTO.Genre = book.Genre;
    bookDetailDTO.Price = book.Price;
    bookDetailDTO.AuthorName = book.AuthorName;

    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.PutAsJsonAsync(url + "/" + id, bookDetailDTO).Result;
    responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Book `DTO` class

```
public class BookDetailDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
}
```

Book Model

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    //public virtual IEnumerable<Author> AuthorID { get; set; }
    // Navigation property
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the method using a debugger?

Comment: You need to debug your software.  a 500 is indicative of a fatal and unhandled error that occurred in API.  You need to specifically look at both the `Content` and the `ReasonPhrase` of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx to determine why the did not accept your put, or simply just let the debugger tell you precisely which line it doesn't care for :).

Comment: Yes, I have.  The debugger goes all the way through fine until the last line of code EnsureSuccessStatusCode().

Comment: @Truecolor and this is almost certainly your bad line `bookEdit.Author.Name = book.AuthorName;` which I'm suspecting is throwing a NullReferenceException.

Comment: I was trying to use the Book Model which I have added in my original post, but I was getting some issues with the `AuthorID` and a View error telling me that I needed a `IEnumerable` AuthorID. That was the reason I created a BookDetailDTO. I cannot figure out how to solve this issue with the `AuthorID` and `Author.Name`.

Comment: You need to step through your `Put` method, *not* the `UpdateBook` service method.

Comment: As Amy said. Also you're not calling the UpdateBook method from your controller so how does that even get called and get to that line?

Comment: @matt_lethargic you have it backwards.  `UpdateBook` calls the controller method using `PutAsJsonAsync`

Comment: Ignore me. Was thinking it was a service inside the API and not calling it.

Comment: That's how I read the question at first, too.  I think its the order each bit was added to the question.